# How to add a value inside an numpy array to a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

i'm trying to loop through a pandas dataframe's columns (which consists of 1's and 0's) to groupby and sum another column then add the groupby column name to an empty dictionary as a key and the summed value as the value.  But my current code adds an array as the value instead of the actual value.  Here is some sample code below.

```
import pandas
sample_dict = {'flag1':[0,1,1,1,1,0],
               'flag2':[1,1,1,0,0,1],
               'flag3':[0,0,0,0,0,1],
               'flag4':[1,1,1,1,0,0],
               'flag5':[1,0,1,0,1,0],
               'dollars':[100,200,300,400,500,600]}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)

ecols = sample_df.columns[:5]
rate = .46
empty_dict = {}
for i in ecols:
    df= sample_df[sample_df[i] == 1]
    yield1 = df.groupby(i)['dollars'].sum().values*rate
    empty_dict[i] = yield1
    
empty_dict
```

That code yields the following output:

```
Out[223]: 
{'flag1': array([644.]),
 'flag2': array([552.]),
 'flag3': array([276.]),
 'flag4': array([460.]),
 'flag5': array([414.])}
```

I would just like to have the actual integer as the value and not the array.

Comment: A true [mcve] in a Pandas question! It deserves a +1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You consistently get an array of one single element: just take its first element (if it has one):

```
...
empty_dict[i] = yield1[0] if len(yield) >=1 else np.nan
...
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting this: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-232-949311df9ecd>", line 9, in <module>
    edit_dict[i] = prem[0]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: @Jordan Could your original code give empty arrays?

Comment: Yes it can have a empty value.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta